# React: Inputs not working anymore after useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following hook that captures `Shift+Enter` key combination and displays an alert and a function

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {  
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.shiftKey) {         
            alert("<br/> Detected Shift+Enter");
            onSubmit();
          }
    })
}, []);
```

The problem is that when loading the component, no input can register informations anymore. But if I remove this `useEffect` everything is working fine. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are registering a top-level event listener that prevents default handling of key events. That's bound to happen. Maybe only `e.preventDefault()` when you detect the special shift-enter combo?

Also, don't forget to unregister the global listener by returning a function from `useEffect`.

You might also want to look at the [react-use library's `useEvent`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useEvent.md) hook.

Answer (score 1):

Here problem is you are using `e.preventDefault();` on keydown.

Once you remove that, inputs will start working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of a keydown event is to enter the character on the downed key into the currently focused input.

You are preventing that.

Don’t.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `e.preventDefault();`. To fix this, you just move it before `onSubmit` and inside `if` block